# How to deploy Libgdx game to iOS

Tags: java, android, ios, libgdx

I have made a game using the Libgdx framework and deployed it to Google Play Store over a month ago. Now I want to deploy it to the Apple app store but the libgdx wiki is not updated on how to deploy to the iOS since RoboVM is discontinued. I am aware of the Intel Multi-OS engine which is supposedly is an alternative to deploy libgdx app to iOS, but I cannot find any tutorials or resources for beginners on how to setup or use it. Can someone provide me clear steps on how to deploy my app to iOS?

PS: I bought a used iMac (4GB ram, with SSD) for this purpose since I heard that it is a requirement to have an OSX machine to make iOS app.

Answer (score 9):

You have two option **MobiDevelop's RoboVM fork** or **Multi-OS Engine**, both are open source.

1. MobiDevelop's RoboVM fork

   Step by steps how [Deploy to iOS](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Deploying-your-application#deploy-to-ios)

   The development and distribution of RoboVM has been discontinued.
    Configure  your system with RoboVM as the given link, RoboVM now denotes MobiDevelop's RoboVM fork.

   The artifactIds stay the same only the Maven artifact coordinates have been changed to groupId `com.mobidevelop.robovm` instead of `org.robovm`.

   Take a look of RoboVM fork  http://robovm.mobidevelop.com/

   If you use MobiDevelop’s RoboVM fork make sure to update your Eclipse/IntelliJ IDEA/Android Studio plugin to version 2.3.0 for libgdx latest version 1.9.5.
2. [Multi-OS Engine](https://multi-os-engine.org)

   The Multi-OS Engine is the full featured solution to develop iOS Apps in Java. It was developed by Intel, based on ART, the Android runtime. The Multi-OS Engine includes the technology acquired from Migeran’s Migeran for iOS product.

   [How to use Multi-OS Engine with LibGDX](https://doc.multi-os-engine.org/multi-os-engine/9_game/1_libgdx/libgdx.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Abhishek Aryan the link you pointed says `This section assumes you're familiar with the basic deployment steps for iOS apps.` do you know any other tutorial for begginers?

Comment: @centenond you can follow https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ otherwise many other tutorial are available [online](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=c3swWciJHebs8Afl-5PADw#q=basic+developement+of+ios+app+tutorial)

Comment: Link to Intel's multi-os-engine shows "discontinued" - is this path no longer a valid option?